# Ubuntu upgrade interferance issue

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-gnome

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 while it was 70% completed I closed the laptop lid after changing the power settings to "do nothing" on close lid. When I lift the lid, the process stopped and I've only been able to login via tty terminal. What do I do?

Comment: What exactly did you see upon opening the lid? The download was paused? An error message that the download had aborted? Something else? Please be detailed.

Comment: ..] dpm_run_callback() : pnp_bus_resume + 0x0/0xao returns - 19

Comment: And pm: device 00:07 failed to resume: error - 19

Comment: @user535733 download wasn't paused because I've already passed the download stage it was just the installation stage and I was no longer connected while it was upgrading. It is just to resume upgrading process that is the issue.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  If any errors please [edit] and post them. You may eventually need also `sudo apt-get install -f`. Other than this there's not much you can do now to salvage that installation. Personally, I would just backup my files and do a clean install, much faster and with better results.

Comment: I tried running sudo apt-get update but it failed. I just tried sudo dpkg - - configure - a and it seems to respond. Let me see how far it goes.

Comment: yeah it did finally.
after running 
sudo dpkg - - configure - a
it continued the upgrade and was successful.
before I ran sudo apt-get update to perform update.  Thanks @MichaelBay and user535733